# символ @ в пакетах npm

Tags: angularjs, npm, rxjs

Здравствуйте.
Объясните, что означает

```
npm install @reactivex/rxjs
```

я понимаю, что это инсталяция пакета, но как-то вроде

```
npm install rxjs
```

начал изучать Angular, TypeScript и постоянно попадается этот символ, например @angular/core или в node_modules/@types
объяснения что сие означает найти не могу...
понимаю, что это банальная какая-то вещь, но ответа найти не могу.

Comment: Я точно не уверен, но мне кажется, что такие символы как @ или / просто не запрещены, это обычные символы в имени пакетов. С их помощью видимо именуют всякие подмодули.

Comment: вот и для babel такой же символ появился для новых версий. npm install babel-loader@8.0.0-beta.0 @babel/core @babel/preset-env webpack. видимо существует какое-то общее соглашение касающееся @... но не могу найти

Answer (score 2):

Это называется scope в терминах npm.

https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/scoped-packages

Кстати, если вы поднимите свой приватный npm-репозиторий (`docker run verdaccio`), то в настройках npm можно указать, чтобы пакеты из такого-то эм.. скоупа загружались из вашего репозитория, а не из публичного, а также туда же и публиковались (чтобы случайне не отправить секреты фирмы в паблик)

Также можно заплатить денег в npm, и тогда они позволят держать приватные репо на их серверах

Публичные же пакеты просто имеют имя типа "@types/react" в package.json и в общем-то это всё.